# SVG links not working after transition executed in d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

The links attached to each element work perfectly before any of the sorting/transition is executed. Below is the code where the links are appended to the rect elements.

```
var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
               .data(data)
               .enter()
               .append("svg:a")
               .attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return d.url })
               .attr("target", "_blank")
               .append("svg:rect")
               ......
```

However, once the below sorting function/transition code is executed, the hyperlinks appended above no longer work. I attempted to again `append` the `<a>` attributes as in the above code, but it did not work..

```
var sortSquares2 = function() {
    svg.selectAll("rect")
         .sort(function(a, b){ return a.order - b.order; })
         .transition()
         .duration(1200)
         ........
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're selecting `rect` elements, but appending `a` elements. Your transition is selecting only the `rect` elements and not the `a` elements and operating on them.

To fix, select and append the same thing. You probably want the highest-level element in this case (i.e. the `a`).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not sure if I understand though. Can you please show me example. In my sort function, do I add all the same code as in my rect variable? Or do I just append the 'a' in my sort function?

Comment: When you're sorting, do `selectAll("a")` and not `selectAll("rect")`.

Comment: If I do this, the links do remain, however only a couple squares from the visualization actually execute a transition. Don't the 'rect' elements also need to be selected?

Comment: Yes, if you are setting attributes on the `rect` elements, you need to select them as well. Similar to how you append them in the first place.

Comment: Thank you again... any chance you can be a bit more specific (more than you already have been)? As you can probably tell, I'm quite a novice, and the things I'm trying based on your suggestions aren't doing the trick.. I'm sure I'm still overlooking something super basic..

Comment: The structure of the code would be `.selectAll("a").attr(...).select("rect").attr(...)`. This is probably not going to work that well with the transitions you have, so alternatively you can do the two separately, i.e. `svg.selectAll("a")...` and then `svg.selectAll("rect")...`.